# How to loop through 100 files to do solidify through script?

Tags: python, scripting

I am new to Blender and I basically need it to help me with just one thing - load and solidify my STL surface mesh to one with 3% thickness. I have learnt how to do it manually. However, I need to apply this on 100 files, and I may need to use other thickness later on.

I tried to play around with the record script add on but can't get it to do what I want. I'm also not familiar with Blender's interface and so it makes thing more difficult. Can someone help? My files has names body_out1.stl to body_out100.stl. I don't know python but I do programming in Fortran though. Thanks!

Comment: If you have some programming background take a swing at it, python is very straightforward language and blender python api is decently documented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```py
import bpy
import glob
import os


def process(stl_fname):
    print('Processing %r' % stl_fname)

    # Determine output filename.
    out_fname = stl_fname.replace('.stl', '-solid.stl')
    if out_fname == stl_fname:
        raise ValueError('stl_fname should end in .stl')

    # Perform the processing.
    bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_fname)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLIDIFY')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].thickness = 0.03
    print('Writing to %r' % out_fname)
    bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=out_fname)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Start with nothing in the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Process *.stl
here = bpy.path.abspath('//')
for stl_fname in glob.glob(os.path.join(here, '*.stl')):
    if '-solid.stl' in stl_fname:
        print('Skipping %r' % stl_fname)
        continue

    process(stl_fname)
```

The code processes all STL files that are in the same directory as the blend file it is run from.

Comment: sorry I was searching around how to accept it as a correct ans