# How to automate this process (SVG to mesh > planar decimation > solidify > collapse decimation) to 300 files?

Tags: python, scripting

I just learned using blender. I set up my first milestone to finish my first task and I did with the help of tutorials and other questions on here. I tried using the record script but with no success whatsoever. I need to convert my svg files into a mesh first, then do a planar decimation with an angle limit 0.1. Then solidify to a thickness of 0.009 and finally do collapse decimation to a ratio of 0.1.

I found a script on here from this post [How to loop through 100 files to do solidify through script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53798/how-to-loop-through-100-files-to-do-solidify-through-script?s=1|34.6563) and tweaked it a little bit. I failed to make it apply for SVGs so I tested it with a couple of stl files and it works perfectly, unfortunately I need to add more to it and my editing is not working well.

When I run this script with just the planar decimation at an angle of 0.1 it does not give me the same outcome as done manually.

I tried using the info header to get a command for a rotation of -97 on the y-axis but it always fails, even when I run it alone; same for the smart UV unwrapping.

Thanks!!

```
import bpy
import glob
import os

def process(stl_fname):
    print('Processing %r' % stl_fname)

    # Determine output filename.
    out_fname = stl_fname.replace('.stl', '-solid.stl')
    if out_fname == stl_fname:
        raise ValueError('stl_fname should end in .stl')

    # Perform the processing.

    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DECIMATE')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].decimate_type = 'DISSOLVE'
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].angle_limit = 0.00174533

    bpy.ops.import_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_fname)
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLIDIFY')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].thickness = 0.009

    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DECIMATE')
    bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].ratio = 0.1

    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[1] = -1.69297

    bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
    bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=89)

    print('Writing to %r' % out_fname)
    bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=out_fname)
    bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Start with nothing in the scene
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.object.delete()

# Process *.stl
here = bpy.path.abspath('//')
for stl_fname in glob.glob(os.path.join(here, '*.stl')):
    if '-solid.stl' in stl_fname:
        print('Skipping %r' % stl_fname)
        continue

    process(stl_fname)
```

Comment: Hi, you probably need to master somewhat python in blender to do what you wish. You "just" need to create a workflow for each SVG, and iterate on all your SVGs. Start showing here what happens when "failed and don't know what is happening"...

Comment: At least make sure that the code you post is actually syntactically correct, and follows PEP-8.

Comment: Can you attach/link to a few STL files so that we can try the same code on the same files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty quick and dirty so be sure to test a small sample 1st, but i think it covers everything you asked for. Running the script will add a toolbar in the 3d view port, the values you had set in the example are properties you can change before importing and exporting all the files in the directories. Have fun with it.

```
import bpy
import os
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.types import Panel
from math import radians

bl_info = {
    "name": "AutoSVG",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 79, 0),
    "location": "View3D > Tools panel 'T' > AutoSVG > AutoSVG",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "",
    }


def makeprop():
    bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_dir_in = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_dir_in",
        description="",
        default="",
        subtype="DIR_PATH",
        )
    bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_decimate_angle = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_decimate_angle",
        description="",
        default=radians(0.00174533),
        subtype="ANGLE",
        )
    bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_thickness = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_thickness",
        description="",
        default=0.009,
        subtype="DISTANCE",
        unit='LENGTH'
        )
    bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_ratio = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_ratio",
        description="",
        default=0.1,
        )
    bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_rotation = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_rotation",
        description="",
        default=radians(-1.69297),
        subtype="ANGLE",
        )
    bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_uv_angle = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name="bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_uv_angle",
        description="",
        default=radians(89),
        subtype="ANGLE",
        )
    bpy.types.Scene.auto_obj_dir_out = bpy.props.StringProperty(
        name="bpy.types.Scene.auto_obj_dir_out",
        description="",
        default="",
        subtype="DIR_PATH",
        )


def delprop():
    del bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_dir_in
    del bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_decimate_angle
    del bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_thickness
    del bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_ratio
    del bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_rotation
    del bpy.types.Scene.auto_svg_uv_angle
    del bpy.types.Scene.auto_obj_dir_out


def begin(scene):
    for files in os.listdir(scene.auto_svg_dir_in):
        if not files.endswith(".svg"):
            print("unexpected file type : ", files)
            continue
        bpy.ops.import_curve.svg(
            filepath=str(os.path.join(scene.auto_svg_dir_in, files)))
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        my_svg = bpy.data.objects['Curve']
        my_svg.select = True
        scene.objects.active = my_svg
        my_svg.name = files.rstrip(".svg")
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DECIMATE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].decimate_type = 'DISSOLVE'
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate"].angle_limit = (
            scene.auto_svg_decimate_angle)
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='SOLIDIFY')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Solidify"].thickness = (
            scene.auto_svg_thickness)
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='DECIMATE')
        bpy.context.object.modifiers["Decimate.001"].ratio = (
            scene.auto_svg_ratio)
        bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[1] = scene.auto_svg_rotation
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='TOGGLE')
        bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=scene.auto_svg_uv_angle)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.export_scene.obj(
            filepath=str(os.path.join(
                scene.auto_obj_dir_out, files.replace(".svg", ".obj"))))
        bpy.ops.object.delete()


class Auto_SVG_Tool():
    @classmethod
    def main(cls, context):
        scene = bpy.context.scene
        print("start button pressed")
        filevalid = ((scene.auto_svg_dir_in is not "") and
                     (scene.auto_obj_dir_out is not ""))
        if not filevalid:
            print("invalid file location or name")
            return
        begin(scene)


class Auto_SVG_Button(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Execute generation"""
    bl_idname = "file.autosvg_operator"
    bl_label = "Generate"

    def execute(self, context):
        Auto_SVG_Tool.main(context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class VIEW3D_PT_Blank1_Blank2(Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'
    bl_category = "AutoSVG"
    bl_context = "objectmode"
    bl_label = "AutoSVG"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(scene, "auto_svg_dir_in", "Input Dir")
        col.separator()
        col.prop(scene, "auto_svg_decimate_angle", "Decimate angle")
        col.prop(scene, "auto_svg_thickness", "Solidify Thickness")
        col.prop(scene, "auto_svg_ratio", "Decimate Ratio")
        col.prop(scene, "auto_svg_rotation", "Object rotation")
        col.prop(scene, "auto_svg_uv_angle", "UV project angle lim")
        col.separator()
        col.prop(scene, "auto_obj_dir_out", "Output Dir")
        col.separator()
        col.operator("file.autosvg_operator", text="Start Files")


def register():
    print("registered")
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_Blank1_Blank2)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Auto_SVG_Button)
    makeprop()


def unregister():
    print("un-registered")
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_Blank1_Blank2)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Auto_SVG_Button)
    delprop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

- changes include:
  PEP8 compliance check via http://pep8online.com.
  Removed several unused options in properties per batFINGER recommendations.
  Invert logic in if statements per Dr. Sybren recommendation reducing indents.
  Exported to .obj instead of .stl to preserve UV's.
  Due to handling of bpy.ops.export_scene.obj() removed debug print commands.
  Renamed curves based on imported file name.

Comment: Remember blender uses radians for angles. (1 radian =  180 / pi degrees). Most readable  method (IMO) is `from math import radians` ,  `default = radians(89)`  Can I suggest too, you can leave out defaults, (eg `get=None`)  in property definitions, and good to use `unit = 'ANGLE'` for angles, and possibly `unit = 'LENGTH'` for thickness.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks for the input, still learning and being self taught I have to say my teacher sucks ;). As for the properties I am currently just using a script to generate them in a fairly bland way to save typing, but like to keep some of the mostly unused options shown in the event i need them. I'm sure a lot of folks could do a cleaner job on the code, and maybe one day I will be able to as well, for now just trying to help if & when I can.

Comment: Another few ways to imrpove the script are to stick to PEP-8 (so don't use capitals in property names), and to flip some conditions. Instead of doing `if good: do stuff; else: print message`, do `if bad: print message and continue/return`. That way your code gets indented less and more readable. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYrPqrFY7mA&t=3207 for more context.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ratt and dr. Sybren, I really appreciate it. The script runs well, but the planar decimation is not giving the same outcome as done manually and the smart uv project doesn't work at all.

Comment: @AGIMZ When exactly are you converting from curve to mesh when you do this manually. Before, after or in the middle of the modifiers being added?

Comment: @Ratt The UV project is still not working after I added the command. Links for the planar decimation https://we.tl/p3XtwwHnEA

Comment: @Ratt  I convert from curve to mesh before all modifiers are added.

Comment: @AGIMZ Apparently the .stl file format does not preserve UV's. So I've altered the script to export as obj. Each export will include a .obj & .mtl file both named based on the original file name.